# Git backup vs SVN

Tags: git, svn, backup, tortoisesvn, tortoisegit

I'm new in Git but I have some experiences on SVN.

I want to make the backup from my project into another computer (for example mine).

In SVN there is a project with branches and tages and for sure trunk.
example url: `https://svn.example.com/project`

When I checkout it I can have a complete copy of the project with tags, branches and etc, so I can zip all and copy each day as a back up on other computer.

Is it something like that on Git? I tried but I couldn't have all of the code in the same time but I can have each part by `switch/checkout`.
[image]

I'm using TortoiseGit.

If you have any other solution please tell me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git works differently to Subversion. In Subversion tags and branches are implemented as different paths. In Git branches and tags are not different paths, but labels/handles to a specific revision (with all its history).

In order to make a complete backup it is sufficient in Git to copy/backup the whole working tree (OR cloning into a bare repository to save space, because then there is no checkout, OR pushing your changes to a remote repository e.g. on GitLab/GitHub).

Every Git repository always (in the normal case) contains ALL history. This works, because Git is a distributed VCS and basically all repositories are equal and none is special (such as in Subversion). There is no central place (sometimes one place is defined to be the central exchange place, but that's not necessary).

Comment: I push the project in a GitHub private repository but there are also 2 other users, and if one of them delete completely the project I'll loose everything about project. So I want to have a copy of the project each day on other computer. I check the `Git bundle` command and I could not have a full backup of the project and it gave me just master. My command: `git bundle create repo.bundle HEAD master`

Comment: A copy of the working tree will give you a full copy. Maybe you need to enable "Show all branches" in TortoiseGit log to see all branches. Check out the reference browser.

Comment: You only loose information of the project if you fetch+prune local remote tracking branches. Otherwise, even if the project or remote branches are deleted on github, they will still be there in your local clone.

Comment: Btw, indeed `git bundle create repo.bundle HEAD master` only backups the `master` and the currently checked out branch, cf. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle

Comment: You know why I became confused because the code size was 4GB but in Git was just 134MB and I thought something was wrong. But, I checked ans saw that 134MB was all the codes history (all I need).